# Why does a Form need a GlobalKey in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

They have used a `GlobalKey` in that `Form`.

From here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html

> Global keys uniquely identify elements. Global keys provide access to
> other objects that are associated with those elements, such as
> BuildContext. For StatefulWidgets, global keys also provide access to
> State.
>
> Widgets that have global keys reparent their subtrees when they are
> moved from one location in the tree to another location in the tree.
> In order to reparent its subtree, a widget must arrive at its new
> location in the tree in the same animation frame in which it was
> removed from its old location in the tree.
>
> Reparenting an Element using a global key is relatively expensive, as
> this operation will trigger a call to State.deactivate on the
> associated State and all of its descendants; then force all widgets
> that depends on an InheritedWidget to rebuild.
>
> If you don't need any of the features listed above, consider using a
> Key, ValueKey, ObjectKey, or UniqueKey instead.

Which feature from above quote is being used in that Form such that it requires a `GlobalKey`?
Why is the GlobalKey required there and why wouldn't any other key work?

Comment: his is because they need `FormState` and they get it via `key.currentState` - you can get `FormState` by calling `Form.of` static method as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the important feature that are using on `GlobalKey` is `formKey.currentState.validate()` method for validating all of `TextFormField` widgets in that `Form`. Because of `GlobalKey` can access to current state of the `FormState`.

In other key type such as `ValueKey` cannot access to the current state of `FormState`.